# How to delete many and keep few objects in big JSON

Tags: json, jq

How to delete many and keep few objects in big JSON file? Here, I have the following JSON file:

```
{
  "service" : {
    "category" : "managed-object",
    "resource" : "object",
    "action" : "locate",
    "options" : {
      "max" : "#VALUE",
      "objectGroupMember" : "#FRESH|DEFAULT",
      "attributes" : {
        "name" : {
          "value" : "#VALUE"
        },
        "state" : "#PREACTIVE|ACTIVE|DEACTIVATED|COMPROMISED|DESTROYED|DESTROYED_COMPROMISED",
        "objectType" : "#VALUE",
        "fresh" : "#YES|NO",
        "objectGroup" : "#VALUE",
        "contactInfo" : "#VALUE",
        "cryptographicAlgorithm" : "#VALUE",
        "cryptographicLength" : "#VALUE",
        "cryptoUsageMask" : "#VALUE",
        "certificateLength" : "#VALUE",
        "certificateType" : "#VALUE",
        "x509CertificateSubject" : "#VALUE",
        "x509CertificateIssuer" : "#VALUE",
        "digitalSigningAlgorithm" : "#VALUE",
        "digest" : {
          "digestValue" : "#VALUE",
          "algorithm" : "#VALUE",
          "keyFormatType" : "#VALUE"
        },
        "link" : {
          "linkType" : "#VALUE",
          "linkValue" : "#VALUE"
        },
        "activationDate" : "#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        "deactivationDate" : "#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        "processStartDate" : "#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        "protectStopDate" : "#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        "initialDate" : "#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        "lastChangeDate" : "#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        "compromiseDate" : "#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        "compromiseOccurrenceDate" : "#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        "destroyDate" : "#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        "archiveDate" : "#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
      },
      "customAttributes" : [ {
        "name" : "#VALUE",
        "value" : "#VALUE",
        "type" : "#TEXT|NUMBER"
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

What jq command deletes everything but:

```
{
  "service" : {
    "category" : "managed-object",
    "resource" : "object",
    "action" : "locate",
    "options" : {
      "attributes" : {
        "name" : {
          "value" : "#VALUE"
        },
      },
      "customAttributes" : [ {
        "name" : "#VALUE",
        "value" : "#VALUE",
        "type" : "#TEXT|NUMBER"
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have searched high and low, and spent a lot of time with trial-and-error, but nothing has really worked. I highly appreciate your support in advance, thank you.
How to delete many and keep few objects in big JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's start by summarising what you're trying to do:

- Drop some fields and keep others in `service.options`
- Drop all fields except `name` in `service.options.attributes`

You also specifically aren't modifying anything else. For example you want to:

- Keep all the fields in `service`
- Keep all the contents of `service.options.customAttributes`

Depending on whether you want to specify the fields to drop or the fields to keep you can modify `service.options` like this:

```
# Specify what to keep...
jq '.service.options|={attributes,customattributes}'

# ...or what to drop
jq 'del(.service.options.max, .service.options.objectGroupMember)'
```

For removing all fields but `name` from `service.options.attributes` it's easiest to specify just what you're keeping:

```
# Specify what to keep
jq '.service.options.attributes|={name}'
```

You can combine these together:

```
jq 'del(.service.options.max, .service.options.objectGroupMember)|.service.options.attributes|={name}'
```

And you can simplify the repetition a fair bit:

```
jq '.service.options|=(del(.max,.objectGroupMember)|.attributes|={name})'
```

All in all, we used:

- `|=` to apply a modification to just part of an object. It's helpful to remember that we can dig deep into a complex object on the left of this operator but our output still keeps all of the higher layers of object unchanged.
- The shortcut syntax of `{name}` to keep only the name field. This is equivalent to `{"name":.name}`.
- `del(.field1, .field2)` to delete fields from an object.

Comment: @OracleTDEandOKV show your appreciation by accepting and/or upvoting answers, see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)