# jq: pick and remove nested fields

Tags: json, key, jq

Here is my json:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "7250078e-5fbf-43d7-9c67-94b88fbf44d8",
    "priority": 0,
    "httpRequest": {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/catalog-data-rest/oid/search.xml",
      "headers": {
        "Host": [
          "preproduccio.gcatalegs.isisscat.intranet.gencat.cat:8443"
        ],
        "Authorization": [
          "Basic VVNVTVBJVFNUOkJ4c2w3MjU5"
        ],
        "User-Agent": [
          "curl/7.58.0"
        ],
        "Accept": [
          "*/*"
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
          "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        ],
        "Content-Length": [
          "94"
        ]
      },
      "keepAlive": true,
      "secure": true,
      "body": {
        "type": "STRING",
        "string": "<request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>1</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>",
        "rawBytes": "PHJlcXVlc3Q+PG9pZD4yLjE2LjcyNC40LjQwMjwvb2lkPjxzdGFydEluZGV4PjE8L3N0YXJ0SW5kZXg+PHBhZ2VTaXplPjEwMDwvcGFnZVNpemU+PC9yZXF1ZXN0Pg==",
        "contentType": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
      }
    },
    "httpResponse": {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "reasonPhrase": "OK",
      "headers": {
        "Date": [
          "Tue, 20 Jul 2021 11:07:40 GMT"
        ],
        "X-Powered-By": [
          "Servlet/3.0"
        ],
        "X-Content-Type-Options": [
          "nosniff"
        ],
        "X-XSS-Protection": [
          "1; mode=block"
        ],
        "Cache-Control": [
          "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
        ],
        "Pragma": [
          "no-cache"
        ],
        "Expires": [
          "0"
        ],
        "Strict-Transport-Security": [
          "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains"
        ],
        "X-Frame-Options": [
          "DENY"
        ],
        "Set-Cookie": [
          "JSESSIONID=0000r6GgpYaB7bQiXRaS8zB8qw8:19pp48tgo; Path=/; HttpOnly"
        ],
        "Keep-Alive": [
          "timeout=10, max=100"
        ],
        "Connection": [
          "Keep-Alive"
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
          "application/xml"
        ],
        "Content-Language": [
          "en-US"
        ],
        "content-length": [
          "29089"
        ]
      },
      "cookies": {
        "JSESSIONID": "0000r6GgpYaB7bQiXRaS8zB8qw8:19pp48tgo"
      },
      "body": {
        "type": "XML",
        "xml": "string-value",
        "rawBytes": "string-value",
        "contentType": "application/xml"
      }
    },
    "times": {
      "remainingTimes": 1
    },
    "timeToLive": {
      "unlimited": true
    }
  }
]
```

I need to remove and pick following fields:

From .httpRequest I need to REMOVE:

```
.httpRequest.headers
.httpRequest.keepAlive
.httpRequest.secure
.httpRequest.body.rawBytes
```

Desired result:

```json
    "httpRequest": {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/catalog-data-rest/oid/search.xml",
      "body": {
        "type": "STRING",
        "string": "<request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>1</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>",
        "contentType": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
      }
    }
```

From .httpResponse I need to PICK:

```
.httpResponse.statusCode
.httpResponse.reasonPhrase
.httpResponse.headers.Content-Type
.httpResponse.headers.content-lenght
```

From .httpResponse I need to REMOVE:

```
.httpResponse.body.rawBytes
```

Desired result would be:

```json
    "httpResponse": {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "reasonPhrase": "OK",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": [
          "application/xml"
        ],
        "content-length": [
          "29089"
        ]
      },
      "body": {
        "type": "XML",
        "xml": "string-value",
        "contentType": "application/xml"
      }
    }
```

So my final json would be:

```json
[
  {
    "httpRequest": {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/catalog-data-rest/oid/search.xml",
      "body": {
        "type": "STRING",
        "string": "<request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>1</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>",
        "contentType": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
      }
    },
    "httpResponse": {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "reasonPhrase": "OK",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": [
          "application/xml"
        ],
        "content-length": [
          "29089"
        ]
      },
      "body": {
        "type": "XML",
        "xml": "string-value",
        "contentType": "application/xml"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I hope I've explained so well.

Up to now I've able to get [this demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iALEgJ6Tqb)

Comment: Putting your own code more in evidence would probably help avoid downvotes

Comment: Is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412090/jq-how-to-delete-many-and-keep-few-objects-in-big-json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a fresh object (using `{}`) when you want to pick, and use `del` when you want to remove.

```
map({
   "httpRequest": (
      .httpRequest |
      del(.headers, .keepAlive, .secure, .body.rawBytes)
   ),
   "httpResponse": (
      .httpResponse |
      del(.body.rawBytes) |
      {
         statusCode,
         reasonPhrase,
         "headers": {
            "Content-Type":   .headers."Content-Type",
            "Content-Length": .headers."content-length"
         },
         body
      }
   )
})
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/JRoMHYNCkj2)

The issue with both this solution and the previously-posted one is that HTTP headers are case-insensitive, so I don't think `.headers."Content-Type"` and `.headers."content-length"` will always work. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: I could have used `"body": ( .body | del(.rawBytes) )` to be a bit more uniform, but I felt that just adds complexity for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could do it:

*parse.jq*

```
# We are only interested in the request and response objects
.[] | [ { httpRequest, httpResponse } ] |

# Delete unwanted paths
del(
    .[].httpRequest.headers,
    .[].httpRequest.keepAlive,
    .[].httpRequest.secure,
    .[].httpRequest.body.rawBytes,
    .[].httpResponse.body.rawBytes
) |

# Reshape the httpResponse object
.[].httpResponse |= 
  ( 
    {
      statusCode,
      reasonPhrase,
      "headers" : {
        "Content-Type"   : .headers."Content-Type",
        "content-length" : .headers."content-length"
      },
      body 
    }
  )
```

Run it like this:

```
jq -f parse.jq infile.json
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "httpRequest": {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/catalog-data-rest/oid/search.xml",
      "body": {
        "type": "STRING",
        "string": "<request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>1</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>",
        "contentType": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
      }
    },
    "httpResponse": {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "reasonPhrase": "OK",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": [
          "application/xml"
        ],
        "content-length": [
          "29089"
        ]
      },
      "body": {
        "type": "XML",
        "xml": "string-value",
        "contentType": "application/xml"
      }
    }
  }
]
```