# Delete all but one key-value pair from JSON

Tags: json, key, jq

I have this:

```json
{
  "service" : {
    "category" : "managed-object",
    "resource" : "attribute",
    "action" : "delete",
    "options" : {
      "uuid" : "#VALUE",
      "attributes" : {
        "name" : {
          "value" : "#VALUE"
        },
        "contactInfo" : "",
        "activationDate" : "",
        "deactivationDate" : "",
        "protectStopDate" : "",
        "processStartDate" : ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need this:

```json
{
  "service" : {
    "category" : "managed-object",
    "resource" : "attribute",
    "action" : "delete",
    "options" : {
      "uuid" : "#VALUE",
      "attributes" : {
        "name" : {
          "value" : "#VALUE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Previously I had a similar problem that was a little bit more complicated, and I received this amazingly simple answer from someone here:

```
.service.options |= (del(.max, .objectGroupMember) | .attributes|={name})
```

That jq command works even here, but of course `(.max, .objectGroupMember)` does not make sense because it does not exist.

How can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1):

I found it in Weeble's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68412440) to my earlier question:

```
'.service.options.attributes |= {name}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A different take on the problem:

```
walk(if type=="object" then with_entries(select(.value!="")) else . end)
```